# How do I edit email template for Events confirmations

Tags: civievent, email, message-templates

I am trying to override the default email template for civicrm Events, which will be sent when registration is complete. I made changes on this file `CRM/Event/Form/EventFees.tpl` but the changes are being shown on email. I tried clearing cache but this doesn't help. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize the style and wording of events email messages in workflow messages here civicrm/admin/messageTemplates?reset=1

Comment: Thank you for the help. It was this template `Events - Registration Confirmation and Receipt (on-line)`